# Firebase Analytics | Possibility of choosing different configuration(JSON) based on selection of value from dropdown

Tags: firebase, configuration, firebase-analytics

I have worked with Firebase Analytics for quite an amount of time and had enough knowledge to integrate Single/Multiple Firebase projects based on the build type and target.

But now, I want to know, Is there any possibility of choosing the different configuration(JSON file) based on the selection of the value from a drop-down

For Instance, After the Application (development build type) is installed and on the login page, I have a drop-down to choose a specific country and based on my selection, Can I choose/configure firebase project ?

I have been trying in Google for few days but still, I haven't seen anything relative to my requirement.

Can Anyone please let me know,Is there any possibility of configuring the firebase project/set up based on drop down values once the Application is installed with specific build type/target ?

Thanks